# Why PHP allows 3; statement?

Tags: php

```
<?php

3;
```

What's such statement for in PHP?

I can't come up with one case that this is useful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, it's "useless" (more formally, it has no effect - the integer three is loaded and then discarded). It follows naturally from two facts:

- `3` is a valid expression (you couldn't use it, e.g. in `$x < 3`, if it wasn't).
- Expressions are also valid statements. *Assignments* are expressions, and you don't want free-standing assignments an error. And even if assignments were made statements, the next example, calls to functions which don't return a meaningful value, is still incredibly common and useful.

Disallowing statements with no effect is both hard (requires quite clever AST analysis and perhaps, for more complex cases, also some AST transformations such as constant folding to make them visible), impossible to get *completely* right (there will always be something that's missed out; doubly so in dynamic languages) and rarely useful.

Note that pretty much all other languages have this tradeoff - either you implement complex compiler passes to disallow it (potentially missing more subtle cases), or ignore it. This even applies to language which have *only* expressions to some extent, except of course that there are no statements and you'd instead call expressions whose value is ignored useless.

Comment: It's not pretty applies to all languages. Languages Like Java, C# will generate an error for this

Comment: @nidhin: Yes, because they decided to accept the tradeoff and give compiler writers another problem to solve. In hindsight, my answer indeed implies languages don't *do* it - edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a case of making it not allowed would be more work than it's worth.  It obviously does nothing useful, so programmers will likely avoid this kind of thing.

One thing to consider is that:

```
some_function("foo");
```

and

```
3;
```

are the syntactically the same.

Comment: Well, not syntactically the same. They are probably even defined in mostly unrelated parts of the grammar. But yes, they are both expressions.

Comment: @delnan: so my point stands. They probably do share many of the same non-terminal symbols in the grammar, "expression" at the very least and probably others.

Answer (score 0):

It's not usefull but allowed.

Every string of code is expression in PHP as 3 too. (ex $v = 17  is exppressions with value int(17) too, `print 17` is also expression with value int(1) )

So code is 
`<?php expr;expr;expr; ?>`

Why it shouldn't be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can do this in JS as well as in Python, I don't know anything else than JS, PHP/Python but it should work well with most, you can safely run these in any of the three `3;` or `'Hello World!';`, please note that you don't need semi colon at the end of statement in Python

Comment: @delnan, agreed, please be kind and do not use your superpowers to pwn and downvote me :D, what I wanted to say was its a valid statement in context of php or python or JS

Answer (score 0):

In a progaming language it's usefull or not is determined by what you write.

A compiler (php is not a complied lang though) will check is their is any syntex error. And it does't have a sense to understand wether it is useful or not. So for php it's valid.

IF WE WRITE THE SAME CODE IN JAVA IT WILL PRODUCE

> Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression
>       The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

iN c# IT WILL PRODUCE

> Error 1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

sO different language have differnt "type checking".

Comment: PHP has a compiler too. And compilers can *try* to find statements that have no effect (sometimes they get very good at it, too).

Comment: @delnan I never say php have no compiler. I said php in not a compiled lang and it's an interpreted one.

Comment: Having an compiler means by definition it's compiled. Perhaps not to native code, but nobody ever said anything about that and it's irrelevant in this case anyway.